# Stuck at 100% on the Noobs Installer

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc, software-installation, noobs

I loaded the Noobs installer on my Raspberry Pi (B+ Model), then chose for both Raspbian & Raspbmc to be installed. I've been waiting for a long time now, it's on 100% and not doing anything (except showing all the "tips"). I'm worried that if I disconnect the pi It will mess up my micro sd card in some way. What should I do? I'm tempted to just disconnect it & try again.

Comment: If you are still waiting, lol, pull the plug and try again -- maybe one OS at a time?

Comment: is it possibly the power supply ( not enough voltage)?

Comment: booting a raspberry pi for the first time -- still a game of chutes and ladders after so many years

Answer (score 4):

Disconnecting the Raspberry Pi will most likely solve the problem. Just remember that disconnecting Rpi straight from the power source will not cause physical nor driver damage to the SD Card. If you do reconnect and you find that the Raspberry Pi does not boot up or acts funny, reformat the SD card & reburn the OS (Noobs Image) back onto the Sd card.

If none of the above fix your issue, I suggest you manually install the image of your desired operating system (E.G: Openelec). The instructions are here: http://raspiserver.ngrok.com/hudenoqosu.mel